# Unable to select only first occurrence of href in anchor tag?

Tags: html, regex, python-2.7, xpath

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="asidemenu_h1">
    <li class="top">
        <h3>Mobiles</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-apple/" title="Apple Mobiles Price">Apple</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-asus/" title="Asus Mobiles Price">Asus</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-black_berry/" title="Black Berry Mobiles Price">Black Berry</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="start2" id="start2ul63" style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">
    <li>
        <h3>Mobiles</h3>
        <ul class="start3 bolder-star">
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-apple/">Apple</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-asus/">Asus</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-black_berry/">Black Berry</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Well I have a solution to this which is Regex but that also selects all 6 links where i only need the first occurrence of all links.

Here is my regex:

```
"/http:\/\/www\.mega\.pk\/mobiles-[A-z]+\//g"
```

Another soulution is xpath but that also doesn't work. Problem is when I write @href it return me nothing but without it i can see all the anchor tags in chrome console.

My xpath is:

```
$x('//*[@id="start2ul63"]/li[1]/ul/li/a[contains(@href,"mobiles-")]/@href')
```

My Python code:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from ScrapyScraper.items import ScrapyscraperItem

class ScrapyscraperSpider(CrawlSpider) :
    name = "rs"
    allowed_domains = ["mega.pk"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-apple/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-asus/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-black_berry/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-gfive/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-gright/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-haier/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-htc/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-huawei/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-lenovo/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-lg/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-motorola/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-nokia/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-oneplus/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-oppo/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-qmobile/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-rivo/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-samsung/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-sony/",
                  "http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-voice/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = ("http:\/\/www\.mega\.pk\/mobiles_products\/\d+\/[A-z-\w.]+",)), callback = 'parse_item', follow = True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response) :
        sel = Selector(response)

        item = ScrapyscraperItem()

        item['Heading'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h2/span/text()').extract()
        item['Content'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/p/text()').extract()
        item['Price'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/text()').extract()
        item['WiFi'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Wireless")]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()').extract()
        item['Battery'] = sel.xpath('(//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Battery")])[1]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()').extract()
        item['Band2G'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"2G (GSM)")]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()').extract()
        item['Band3G'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"3G (UMTS)")]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()').extract()
        item['Band4G'] = sel.xpath('(//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"4G LTE")])[1]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()').extract()
        item['Screensize'] = sel.xpath('(//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Screen size")])[1]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()').extract()
        item['Storage'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Internal storage space")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()').extract()
        item['CameraStatus'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Built-in c")]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()').extract()

        if (item['CameraStatus'] == [u'Yes']) :
            item['BCamera'] = sel.xpath('(//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Camera Pixels")])[1]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()').extract()
            item['NofCamera'] = sel.xpath('substring(//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(., "Number of cam")]/following-sibling::td[1], 1, 1)').extract()
            if (item['NofCamera'] == [u'2']) :
                item['FCamera'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Resolution 2nd c")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()').extract()
            else :
                pass
        else :
            item['CameraStatus'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Built-in c")]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()').extract()

        return item
```

Comment: Did you try `//*[@id="start2ul63"]/li/ul/li/a[contains(@href,"mobiles-")][1]/@href` XPath? To access the first found value, you need to use `[1]`. No wonder you could not access a nodeset @href attribute value.

Comment: Problem is with /@href i get [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]

Comment: How/where do you get this? I cannot find it in the console.

Comment: I am directly doing it in chrome console with this website http://www.mega.pk/mobiles/.

Comment: Try `var ns = $x('//*[@id="start2ul63"]/li/ul/li/a[contains(@href,"mobiles-")]');
arr = []
for (var i = 0; i < ns.length; i++)
{
   if (arr.indexOf(ns[i].getAttribute("href")) === -1) {
        arr.push(ns[i].getAttribute("href"))
    }
}
console.log(arr);`

Comment: I have a limitation in my framework, so i can't use javascript. Only xpath 1.0 is allowed.

Comment: But I used it "directly inside the Chrome console". What framework do you use? Do you mean you need a fully XSLT solution? Why haven't you added that tag then?

Comment: I am using scrapy framework, which supports xpath. I have searched alot but i have no idea why /@href returns empty list.

Comment: Try [`scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml): ***restrict_xpaths** (str or list) – is an XPath (or list of XPath’s) which defines regions inside the response where links should be extracted from. If given, only the text selected by those XPath will be scanned for links.* Use the `'//*[@id="start2ul63"]/li/ul/li/a[contains(@href,"mobiles-")]'` there. And use basic Python code to [delete dup array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/python-removing-duplicates-in-lists).

Comment: @stribizhev I have reverted the steps back to where my scraper was working correctly as I could not get anything to work. But have added the code in my original post.

Comment: If you are in for some guidance or help, I'll discuss what I was trying to do as later on I'll have to find way some way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use negative look ahead assertion, following regex only match last occurrence of each link

```
"/(http:\/\/www\.mega\.pk\/mobiles-\w+\/)(?!.*\1)/gs"
```

**[Explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/sN6hS9/3)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: without g it returns only the 1st link.

Comment: Can you please explain whats wrong with my xpath expression?

Comment: @MansoorAkram : sorry I'm not familiar with it